# Python Lambda function takes twice as many calls to execute compared to functools.partial

Tags: python, function, lambda, functools

I'm fairly new to python so this might be a very basic question.

I'm using lambda function to pass some arguments to a function call in a GUI for a plug-in that I'm working on (Autodesk Maya). Works perfectly fine.

I also considered using functools.partial for this and tried to decide by "benchmarking" the two calls:

```
import cProfile, pstats
from io import StringIO
import functools

class Profiler():

    def __init__(self):
        self.pr = cProfile.Profile()
        self.pr.enable()

    def end(self):
        self.pr.disable()
        s = StringIO()
        sort = 'tottime'
        ps = pstats.Stats(self.pr, stream=s).sort_stats(sort)
        ps.print_stats()
        print(s.getvalue())

class SimpleClass:

    def method(self,x,y):
        return x * y

simpleClass = SimpleClass()

lmbd = lambda: simpleClass.method(2,2)
fnct = functools.partial(simpleClass.method,2,2)

num = 10000000

profiler = Profiler()
for i in range(num):
    lmbd()
profiler.end()

profiler = Profiler()
for i in range(num):
    fnct()
profiler.end()
```

However, profiler shows that lambda function takes much more time to execute and it has twice as many calls, functools.partial however is much faster and works as expected.

```
         20000002 function calls in 2.462 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 10000000    1.780    0.000    2.462    0.000 c:/Users/George/Desktop/bench.py:26(<lambda>)   
 10000000    0.683    0.000    0.683    0.000 c:/Users/George/Desktop/bench.py:21(method)     
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 c:/Users/George/Desktop/bench.py:11(end)        
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}

         10000002 function calls in 0.678 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 10000000    0.678    0.000    0.678    0.000 c:/Users/George/Desktop/bench.py:21(method)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 c:/Users/George/Desktop/bench.py:11(end)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Can someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong here and why there is such a huge difference?

Comment: With the lambda expression, the wrapped call is visible. With `partial`, the wrapped call is buried deeper in the implementation, so isn't visible to the profiler.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct. If I measure by just using datetime it will show that partial is about 20% faster, but at least the results are similar. Thank you.